# JavaScript naming object functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Fairly new to JS,

Using a simple example of an object with a function:

```
var person = {
    name: "Bob McBobson",
    talk: function descriptiveFunctionName() {alert("Hello");}
};
```

I've noticed you can name object functions (e.g. descriptiveFunctionName above)

Are there any cases where this would be needed/helpful rather than leaving anonymous?

Comment: It's my understanding that `descriptiveFunctionName` is only available inside the function itself.  I say "its my understanding" because I'm not 100% on this.  You can test this by changing the alert to `alert(descriptiveFunctionName)`.

Comment: @Amy - You're correct (well, there and as the `name` property on the function [as of ES2015] and in stack traces).

Comment: javascript engines use function names to make better stack traces. this makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @snek Looking at one of the answers it suggests in my example the function would be named 'Talk' do you know if that would show in the stack?

Comment: @DogBoy - Yes, in most modern engines. And eventually, probably in all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any cases where this would be needed/helpful rather than leaving anonymous?

As of ES2015, even if you left out `descriptiveFunctionName` there, your function wouldn't be anonymous, it would have a name (`talk`). ES2015 added *inferred function names* (and the `name` property, finally). Names are inferred in the majority of situations, with the only really important place they *aren't* inferred being `obj.foo = function() { }` (which leaves the function with the name `""`, not `"foo"`).

Separately, if the function will be recursive or otherwise refer to itself (set itself as an event handler, etc.), you may prefer to reference it by its name (which is in-scope within it).

So, reasons for adding the name:

1. If you're creating the object as shown in your question and you want the function's actual name not to match the property you're initializing with the function.
2. If you're doing `obj.foo = function nameHere() { };` and you want the function to have a name rather than `""`.
3. It will refer to itself and you want to use that name rather than the object property.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason you might want to do it is so you can retrieve the function's name later.  So if you could assign the variable to one of many functions and then later want to see which one you assigned you can recall it with `.name`.

```js
var parent = { myFunc: undefined };
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
switch (rnd) {
  case 0: parent.myFunc = function subtract(x) { return x - 1; }; break;
  case 1: parent.myFunc = function add(x) { return x + 1; }; break;
  case 2: parent.myFunc = function multiply(x) { return x * 2; }; break;
}

console.log(parent.myFunc.name); // subtract, add, or multiply
```